# CSE (Custom Search Engine) steps

Tags: android, ssl, google-custom-search

**EDIT**

...I'm still wondering why I can't find a solution to this issue.
I verify the API Key and the Custom Search Engine ID.
May be I left some library?

I have (related to the question):

*-GWT SDK*

*-validation-api*

I'm still reading posts and documentation....but nothing works....

**ORIGINAL**

I'm trying to develop an Android app. using CSE (Custom Search Engine). I've read a lot about this issue (here and in everywhere), but right now I'n not sure about anything: it's a mess for me.
I would like to know if I'm in the right way.

1. I get the API access key and the CSE ID
2. I want to use my own CSE, so I have to open a connection using "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=_MY_API_KEY_&cx=_MY_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID&q=_MY_QUERY_

Here is the piece of code:

```
            URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=_MY_KEY_&cx=_MY_ID_&q=tomcat");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

I get an SSL exception at

**InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());**

**javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer.**

I don't know how I could fix this error, because all the examples I found related to CSE have (more or less) the same code to connect to the custom url search.

This is my first time here, so I not sure if I've expressed myself in the proper way.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Isaac.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access a secure url (https) while using HttpURLConnection (instead HttpsURLConnection, mind the 's'), therefore the ssl error. Change to secure call and see if it worked.

To check if the engine is working as intended, just paste the url you mentioned ("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=_MY_API_KEY_&cx=_MY_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID&q=_MY_QUERY_") in the browser - if it works, the engine is alright and the problem is in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the response Devnook. I've tried to use HttpsURLConnection, changed the URL to "https://www.google.com" and to simplify the code just opening the connection and reading the buffer. Also, my custom URL works properly in the browser. Always the same error...I'll be working on it. For sure, there's something that I've missed....